# mysql: find highest average score

Tags: mysql

I've written a query that pulls out the average score per player who was in inning 4:

```
SELECT batsmen.player_id, AVG(score)
FROM batsmen
WHERE batsmen.inning_no=4
GROUP BY player_id;
```

But now I need to find the highest average score.  obviously i could look at the output, orderby and easily see the highest average, but i would like a query that pulls it out for me.

I assume somehow i need to use

```
SELECT MAX(score);
```

with the result set received in my avg query above.  Do I need to join/subquery?

Thanks
Theresa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will fill your needs:

```
SELECT player_id, AVG(score)
FROM batsmen
WHERE batsmen.inning_no=4
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks very much - this is the one!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try this:

```
SELECT player_id, avg_score
FROM (
  SELECT batsmen.player_id, 
    AVG(score) avg_score
  FROM batsmen 
  WHERE batsmen.inning_no=4 
  GROUP BY player_id
)
ORDER BY avg_score DESC
LIMIT 0,1;
```

C.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't pick out the highest average.  I changed a little bit and I get the correct output using "SELECT player_id, MAX(average)
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(score) AS average, player_id FROM batsmen where batsmen.inning_no=4 group by batsmen.player_id 
   ) AS highest_average;" BUT even though the average is correct - the player ID is incorrect (it should be 103 but it is showing as 1). Thanks

Comment: I can see why your solution doesn't work as expected, but I don't understand why mine doesn't give you what you asked for. Try it again without the LIMIT and check the result.

You could extend your method by using the MAX(CONCAT(LPAD trick to create a single composite field out of the two values (try Google for examples)

Answer (score -1):

I believe the SQL should be:

```
SELECT MAX(
 SELECT AVG(score)
 FROM batsmen
 WHERE batsmen.inning_no=4 
 GROUP BY player_id
);
```